# Did Quine change of opinion towards quantified modal logic?

Tags: logic, modal-logic, quine, quantification

Willard Van Orman Quine was a strong opponent to quantified modal logic calling it unreasonable and useless. But, did he always think like that? Or did he relax his attitude towards it with time? Did he ever consider it in his works?

Comment: See [Tuboly, Quine and Quantified Modal Logic](https://www.academia.edu/12217424/Quine_and_Quantified_Modal_Logic_Against_the_Received_View) and [Quine's paper Propositional Objects](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40103900) for his own austere version of "possible worlds".